# How to turn one list element in two?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

lets say i have a list like this:

```
bla = ['3,00 € 3,50 €\r\n', '3,00 €\r\n', '6,50 €\t5,50 €\r\n']
```

Every time I have two prices in one item I want to turn this item in two Items.
So it looks like this:

```
['3,00 €', '3,50 €', '3,00 €', '6,50 €', '5,50 €']
```

Comment: are you sure you want to keep the \r\n, tab chars?

Comment: No i dont want them :)

Comment: I edited the question for you then, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex: Split according to euro sign and reformat, flattening the list in the process, and stripping all blanks:

```
bla = ['3,00 € 3,50 €\r\n', '3,00 €\r\n', '6,50 €\t5,50 €\r\n']

result = ["{} {}".format(x.strip(),"€") for item in bla for x in item.split("€") if x.strip()]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['3,00 €', '3,50 €', '3,00 €', '6,50 €', '5,50 €']
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract all prices matching the `<digits>,<digits> €` pattern with a regular expression and flatten the result list:

```
import re
l = [item for s in [re.findall("[0-9]+,[0-9]+\s?€", x) for x in bla] for item in s]
```

**Edit:**

Even shorter, join your list to a single string and extract all the strings matching said pattern:

```
l = re.findall("[0-9]+,[0-9]+\s?€", " ".join(bla))
```

Comment: This could be simpified to `[m for x in bla for m in re.findall("[0-9]+,[0-9]+\s?€", x)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's (yet another) way to do it without regular expressions:

```
from itertools import chain

bla = ['3,00 € 3,50 €\v\n', '3,00 €\v\n', '6,50 €\t5,50 €\v\n']

result = [r for r in chain.from_iterable(((v+' €' for v in (y.strip()
                                                    for y in s.split('€') if y.strip()))
                                                        for s in bla))]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['3,00 €', '3,50 €', '3,00 €', '6,50 €', '5,50 €']
```